# WKWebView Disable horizontal scroll and wrap content

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

This "up up up up" in the below picture is an html string load in wkwebview with using

```
webView?.loadHTMLString((currentLock?.text)!, baseURL: nil)
```

and on

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    webView.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.5
    webView.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 20
    webView.scrollView.setZoomScale(1.5, animated: true)
}
```

Now I want it to have only vertical scroll and horizontal content size equal to the frame width. Currently it contents spread to full horizontal scroll I am intent to wrap it horizontally equal to the frame width and allow only vertical scroll to see the full message.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
try to add html content inside Paragraph to wrap it up. 

Eg: -  <p> Add Html content inside the paragraph to wrap <math xmlns=“http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML”><mfrac><mn>1</mn><mn>200</mn></mfrac><msqrt><mo>&#177;</mo><msup><mi>s</mi><mn>2</mn></msup></msqrt></math> </p>
```

I think this solves the issue in Wkwebview if user is loading htmlString.

```
let htmlString = "<p>up up up up up up up up </p>"
webView?.loadHTMLString(htmlString, baseURL: nil)
```